# R code to detect a change in a variable over time for multiple patients

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a data set with multiple rows per patient, where each row represents a 1-week period of time over the course of 4 months. There is a variable `grade` that can take on values of `1`,`2`,or `3`, and I want to detect when a single patient's grade INCREASES (1 to 2, 1 to 3, or 2 to 3) at any point (the result would be a yes/no variable). I could write a function to do it but I'm betting there is some clever functional programming I could do to make use of existing R functions. Here is a sample data set below. Thank you!

`df=data.frame(patient=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),period=c(1,2,3,1,3,1,3,4,5),grade=c(1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,3))`

what I would want is a resulting data frame of:

`data.frame(patient=c(1,2,3),grade.increase=c(0,1,1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(patient, period) %>%
  mutate(grade.increase = case_when(grade > lag(grade) ~ TRUE,TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  summarise(grade.increase = max(grade.increase))
```

Combining `lag` which checks the previous value with `case_when` allows us to identify each grade.increase.

Summarising the maximum of grade.increase for each patient gets the desired results as boolean calculations treat FALSE as 0 and TRUE as 1.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there would be an elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like doing this in base R, here's a solution that uses the split-apply-combine approach.

- You use `split` to make a list with a separate data frame for each patient;
- you use `lapply` to iterate a summarization function over each list element, where the summarization function uses `diff` to look at changes in `grade` and `if` and `any` to summarize; and then
- you wrap the whole thing in `do.call(rbind, ...)` to collapse the resulting list into a data frame.

Here's what that looks like:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df[,"patient"]), function(i) {

    data.frame(patient = i[,"patient"][1],
               grade.increase = if (any(diff(i[,"grade"]) > 0)) 1 else 0 )

}))
```

Result:

```
  patient grade.increase
1       1              0
2       2              1
3       3              1
```